# Need to run httpd and jetty on the same centos7 server

Tags: httpd, jetty

I have a VPS with CentOS7 with httpd + php running on 80 port and let's say with `domainOne.tld`.

All of the web files are in `/var/www/html`.

Now I need to run a java application on jetty on another domain, let's say `domainTwo.tld`.

If I just install jetty it will be on 8080 port while httpd is on 80. They should work okay I guess, but is it possible to attach `domainTwo.tld` to jetty's 8080 port while it not be accessed on `domainOne.tld:8080` ?

Comment: Set up Apache as a reverse proxy for Jetty.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of [this search](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=apache%20reverse%20proxy). It has been asked and answered many times already.

Comment: In my defense I want to say that I can use search. The problem was that I had no clue that I have to use reverse proxy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).  Something like this should work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domainOne.tld
  #put info to point to your PHP app here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domainTwo.tld

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: mod_proxy works, thanks. if I want to use https do I just remove the 80's port virtualhost and create one for 443 port. I'm not very good in servers.

Comment: Yes that would work, you will also need to add a certificate and key.

Comment: Hi again, I had a little problem with your example. Just saw it. I enabled `mod_proxy` in httpd.conf by writing `LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so` and `LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so` and used your virtualhost example. In servername I wrote `domainTwo.tld` and it worked but it worked and for `domainOne.tld`. So I added anotehr virtual host: `</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domainOne.tld
  ServerAlias *.domainOne.tld
</VirtualHost>` Am I doing this right?

Comment: Think I read your request wrong, I thought you want httpd in front of jetty which is what mod_proxy would do.  I updated the example above to what I think you are trying to do.  The first virtualhost is for php and the second is for jetty.